# java process hangs on start

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I have a server (40GB RAM) on which the java process hangs on start.
If I simply type "java" on the shell, it prints the help message and then never exits.

It appears that there are about 8GBs of RAM available. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what the output of top looks like:

Tasks: 297 total,   1 running, 296 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us, 19.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 79.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  49556016k total, 41112432k used,  8443584k free,   286900k buffers
Swap: 97851904k total,   276044k used, 97575860k free, 23982784k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
   13 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S   88  0.0   2302:14 ksoftirqd/3
   25 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S   73  0.0   2782:56 ksoftirqd/7
    4 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S   64  0.0  10223:40 ksoftirqd/0
 4912 user1   20   0 1529m 211m 9.8m S   25  0.4   6510:25 java
13092 user2   20   0 6565m 2.6g 8472 S   18  5.6   3178:40 java
    1 root      20   0 19428  860  420 S    0  0.0   9:32.65 init

Comment: which JRE are you using?

Comment: java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Have you tried to connect with JConsole to the process ?

Comment: PS: Running that command promptly caused the process to hang after it displayed that information on the screen

Comment: Can you try -Xmx256m or some small value for the heap. Can you use jstack  to get the thread dump?

Answer (score 0):

`java -version` should exit almost immediately. If it doesn't its not installed correctly.

BTW Try installing Java 6 update 33 as update 20 is quite old.